# Can I reference a gemfile in a subdirectory/submodule?

Tags: ruby, gemfile

I have two git modules A and B. B is a submodule (thus a subdirectory) of A. I have some ruby scripts in B that I need to call from A. Module A itself doesn't have any Ruby code (so no need for Gemfile). I have a Gemfile in B that lists the dependencies for the scripts in B. However to call these scripts from A I have to move the Gemfile up into A:

```
cd A
mv B/Gemfile .
bundle update
bundle install
bundle exec ruby B/someScript.rb
```

Is there a way I can call a script in B without having to first move the Gemfile up into A?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply move terminal to subfolder - B (submodule) and run the script. Anyhow A doesn't have any ruby code, so its fine to move terminal to B subfolder while running the script. That will be easy to manage submodule.

```
cd A/B
bundle update
bundle install
bundle exec ruby someScript.rb
```

If you really want it to be in A, then follow below Gemfile

> Gemfile

```
# Gemfile inside project A
source 'http://rubygems.org/'

eval_gemfile File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "B/Gemfile")
```

Comment: I like the second part. The ruby code in `B` still references a config file in `A` so I need to run the code from `A`.